# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in

Tags: php, mysql

В php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

на установку

```
/etc/apache2$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-pdo
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Заметьте, вместо «php7.2-pdo» выбирается «php7.2-common»
Уже установлена самая новая версия php7.2-common.
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 python-compizconfig
Для их удаления используйте «apt-get autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 212 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. С mysqli такая история.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysqli
[sudo] password for me: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет php-mysqli — виртуальный, его функции предоставляются пакетами:
  php7.3-mysql 7.3.4-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+3
  php7.0-mysql 7.0.33-6+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+3
  php7.2-mysql 7.2.17-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+3
Вы должны явно указать, какой именно вы хотите установить.

E: Для пакета «php-mysqli» не найден кандидат на установку
~$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqli
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Заметьте, вместо «php7.2-mysqli» выбирается «php7.2-mysql»
Уже установлена самая новая версия php7.2-mysql.
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 python-compizconfig
Для их удаления используйте «apt-get autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 212 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Comment: у меня что pdo, что мюсли и так работают, без установки модулей.. просто с репо ставил пакеты

Comment: Сейчас задам глупый вопрос, но что делать в моей ситуации? Сам php работает, нот как заставить запахать mysql. Мне очень нужна база.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: "Уже установлена самая новая версия mysql-server."